# Qwt Plot - Is it possible to have multiple y-axes with different scales?

Tags: c++, qt, plot, qwt

I need to have different lines on my plot, with very different values.
One line has values approximately from -4.5 to 4.5, another - from 0 to 10,000.
I need to have them both on one plot, one connected to the left y-axis, another to the right.
And I want to still have a zooming option, so the axes should be both autoscaled.

I tried setting two different axes to different plots with `setAxes()`, but they are still connected to the left y-axis.

All the forums I read on this question are unclear whether it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

First on your QwtPlot :

```
setAxisScale( yLeft, 0, 1.8,0.5 );
setAxisScale( yRight, 0, 1000, 0.5 );
```

Then use on your graph:

```
curve->setYAxis(yRight);
curve2->setYAxis(yLeft)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I tried it. The curve just doesn't get associated with the right axis. And also, I need it to be autoscaled.

Comment: please show a minimal example of your code then. Autoscaling was not in your original question.